# Working with numbers extracted from string

Tags: php, numbers, substring

I'm new to php and I understand I'm making some stupid mistake but the code seems to work even if results are different from expected.

I'm trying to change a string like "To step 1" into something like "To step 2" but I'm unable to extract number and increment it.

I've seen lots of questions and tried many ways as in the code below.

Please show me where I'm wrong.

**EDIT: I noticed that $CurStep seems to have no value in the else block**

```
$CurStep='To step 1';
echo $CurStep.'<br>';
  if($CurStep=null){
      $BtnFwdName='To step 1';
      $BtnBackName=null;
      $Step=0;
  }else{
      $Step=substr($CurStep,-1,1);
      echo '<br>step substr='.$Step;
      $Step=filter_var($CurStep, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
      echo '<br>step filter='.$Step;
      $Step= $CurStep;
      preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$Step);
      echo '<br>step replace='.$Step[0];
      $BtnBackName="To step ".$Step-1;
      $BtnFwdName="To step ";
      $BtnFwdName.=$Step+1;
      echo '<br>step final='.$Step;
  }
echo '<br>BtnFwdName='.$BtnFwdName;
echo '<br>';
echo 'BtnBackName='.$BtnBackName;
```

N.B. I've also tested this code on http://phptester.net/ to check if it was a my pc fault but the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.change***

`if($CurStep=null){ // this is not comparison,it's an assignment`

To:-

`if($CurStep==null){ // now it's an assignment`

***2.I*** don't know why you did that much stuff. You can easily do like below:-

```
<?php

$CurStep='To step 1';
// explode string to make it an array
$exploded_array = explode(' ',$CurStep);
// increase the last value of array to 1
$exploded_array[count($exploded_array)-1] = $exploded_array[count($exploded_array)-1]+1;
// again convert array to string and echo it
echo $newcurStep = implode(' ',$exploded_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/875629

Note:- in the same way you can go for `To step 0` also (*instead of +1 do -1*). If you can't let me know. I will add that too